# I need to add a filter to prepend the term 'National - ' to the post title if the post is tagged to multiple states

Tags: custom-post-types, php, filters, taxonomy

I am trying to add a filter to add the word "National - " to the beginning of the the post title if the post has multiple states that it is in.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I just figured out the add filter that adds the word "National - " to the beginning of the post title, but I can't figure out the if statement because I only need the word "National - to be added if the post has multiple states.

Here is the filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function($title) { 
return 'National - ' . $title;
});
```

Comment: Why did you remove the text of your question? I'm going to restore it; the point of a Q&A site like this is to answer your question, as well as anyone else who might have a similar question. Removing the question once it's answered defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "states" appear to be terms in a custom taxonomy. In the code below I've assumed the taxonomy's name is `my_state`; you'll need to make sure that's updated to match the actual taxonomy name.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title, $id ) {
    // Gets the list of 'states' the post belongs to.
    $states = wp_get_post_terms( $id, 'my_state' );
    // If there's more than 1 state, prepend 'National - ' to the title.
    if ( 1 < count( $states ) ) {
        $title = 'National - ' . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

### References

- [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/)